# Styling API XML response

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following example response that I need to format but all the examples I have seen around don't quite match so I am completely lost in turning it to XSLT. What I would like to have is a simple table easy for humans to read.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApiResponse Status="OK" xmlns="http://api.domain.com/xml.response">
  <Errors />
  <Warnings />
  <RequestedCommand>namecheap.users.getpricing</RequestedCommand>
  <CommandResponse Type="namecheap.users.getPricing">
    <UserGetPricingResult>
      <ProductType Name="domains">
        <ProductCategory Name="register">
          <Product Name="com">
            <Price Duration="1" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.98" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.98" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.98" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="2" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.88" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.88" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.88" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="3" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.78" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.78" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.78" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="4" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.68" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.68" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.68" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="5" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.58" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.58" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.58" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="6" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.58" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.58" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.58" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="7" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.58" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.58" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.58" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="8" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.58" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.58" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.58" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="9" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.58" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.58" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.58" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
            <Price Duration="10" DurationType="YEAR" Price="10.58" PricingType="MULTIPLE" AdditionalCost="0.18" RegularPrice="10.58" RegularPriceType="MULTIPLE" RegularAdditionalCost="0.18" RegularAdditionalCostType="MULTIPLE" YourPrice="10.58" YourPriceType="MULTIPLE" YourAdditonalCost="0.18" YourAdditonalCostType="MULTIPLE" PromotionPrice="0.0" Currency="USD" />
          </Product>
        </ProductCategory>
      </ProductType>
    </UserGetPricingResult>
  </CommandResponse>
  <Server>PHX01APIEXT02</Server>
  <GMTTimeDifference>--4:00</GMTTimeDifference>
  <ExecutionTime>0.063</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

Comment: Could you please add your idea of what *a simple table easy ... to read* should look like?

Comment: What have you tried so far (in the sense of XSLT)?

Comment: @Filburt Just a simple table with rows for each Duration, a header row and a headline that mentions the TLD.

Comment: @zx485 I haven't tried much since I have no experience with XSLT. What I tried based on something I found online, didn't work. It produced an HTML file but it was empty, no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated XML shared via the link in the comments, the `html` output can be achieved using the following solution.

The list of attributes for the `<Price>` element is different for different `<Product>`. In the output the attribute values need to be displayed below the appropriate column.

A key is defined for the attribute names

```
<xsl:key name="key-attr-name" match="res:Price/@*" use="name(.)"/>
```

The key is used to get the unique names when generating the header row.

```
<tr>
    <th>ProductCategory</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="(//res:Price/@*)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('key-attr-name', name(.))[1])]">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

Similarly, the key will be used to populate the values of the attributes as data in the table.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//res:Price">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::res:ProductCategory/@Name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::res:Product/@Name" /></td>
        <xsl:variable name="curr-price" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="(//res:Price/@*)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('key-attr-name', name(.))[1])]">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$curr-price/@*[name(.) = name(current())]" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For your comment *It produced an HTML file but it was empty, no rows.*, the reason could be no declaration of the namespace `http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response` in the XSLT. The input XML has a namespace associated with it which needs to be declared in the XSLT also and the elements belonging to the namespace should be accessed using a prefix (alias) viz. `res:Price`. Below is how you can declare the namespace and omit the prefix in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:res="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response" exclude-result-prefixes="res">
```

The complete XSLT and output is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:res="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response" exclude-result-prefixes="res">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="key-attr-name" match="res:Price/@*" use="name(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ProductCategory</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <xsl:for-each select="(//res:Price/@*)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('key-attr-name', name(.))[1])]">
                            <th><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//res:Price">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::res:ProductCategory/@Name" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::res:Product/@Name" /></td>
                            <xsl:variable name="curr-price" select="."/>
                            <xsl:for-each select="(//res:Price/@*)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('key-attr-name', name(.))[1])]">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$curr-price/@*[name(.) = name(current())]" />
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each> 
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: How about if I had more ProductCategory nodes, Product nodes and I wanted their names to appear on the first two columns of the table like this: `<tr>
                <td>biz</td>
                <td>REGISTER</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>YEAR</td>
                <td>10.98</td>`

Comment: it won't let me edit it because it contains too much code in relationship with the text but you can get it from here: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SWykAs_g41VqiIArQwpq3IluRgGH0wm_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you have the privilege of using XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: I am not sure what that is, sorry! I have an app on my mac that I can input an XML file, an XLST file and it transforms the XML to HTML.

Comment: Since the number of attributes are not same for every `<Price>` it is going to be complex to use XSLT 1.0 as the attribute value needs to be put under appropriate header.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. So a wildcard won't do it, you need to create/declare the columns for each one of the attributes, correct?

Comment: I have updated the solution according to the new input XML.